# How to extend a trendline to the x-intercept

Tags: sql, linear-regression, presto, trendline

I am working on a chart showing a burndown of task completion, and I have a trendline plotted against my data that's working nicely. Here is the trendline SQL query, done in Presto:

```
SELECT
ds,
ds 
* REGR_SLOPE(COUNT(task_id), ds) OVER ()
) + (
    REGR_INTERCEPT(COUNT(task_id) AS DOUBLE, ds) OVER ()
) AS trend
FROM tasks_db
WHERE
ds >= '<CURDATE-7>'
AND (some criteria...)
GROUP BY
ds
```

The issue is that the trendline stops when my data stops at the current date. I would like to project it beyond that to the point where we hit 0. (Let's worry about upward-sloping burndowns another day).

I thought I could potentially do a union with a "SELECT 0, x-intercept" but I am having trouble figuring out how to structure the query. Referencing data from the earlier SELECT statement doesn't seem possible, and I can't quite reverse engineer the formula to project the x-intercept.